# Probability of one golfer beating another with probabilities p(player 1 wins the hole), ....

Tags: probability

Two golfers are playing sudden death to decide a tournament. The first one wins a hole with probability p, the second one wins with probability q, and holes are tied with probability r. Holes are independent, and the game stops the first time someone wins a hole. What is the probability that the first player wins?

Comment: I'm thinking it would have to be the probability of the first player winning the first + probability of tying first and winning second + probability of tying first and second and winning 3rd + .... and so on.

Comment: Would a tie factor in player 2 losing (1-q)? Would I have to multiply the probability of a tie times the probability of q losing, or are they related somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The probability of the first player winning is
$$p+rp+r^2p+\cdots=\frac{p}{1-r}=\frac{p}{p+q}\ .$$
Note that this agrees with the following intuitive argument: since draws are irrelevant, ignore $r$.  Then the ratio of probabilities is $p:q$, which gives the above probability for a first-player win.

Comment: It makes sense. How much confidence do you have in this answer?

Comment: ??? I think the answer is correct, if that's what you mean ;-)

Comment: It is solid. Why do you ask?

Comment: It just feels soo simple to be one of my four problems assigned. I guess problems that don't use numbers and want the answer in general terms always confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Let A be the player who has probability $p$ of winning a hole, and let $a$ be the probability she ultimately wins. We condition on the result of the first hole. If A wins that hole, she wins. If she ties the first hole, then she has probability $a$ of ultimately winning. Thus
$$a=p+ra,$$
and therefore $a=\frac{p}{1-r}$. Note that $1-r=p+q$, so an alternate form of the answer is $a=\frac{p}{p+q}$.

**Remark:** This approach is in my opinion much less nice than the "neglect ties" idea of David. But conditioning on the result of the first "game" is a useful tool in probability and expectation calculations.